# How to select dataframe row using regular expression on the index column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a pandas newbie.
Here's the problem with an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['john','joe','zack']})
```

I know that I can select rows where the "id" column contains "jo" like so

```
mask = df['id'].str.contains('jo')
df[mask]
```

But suppose that id column is indexed

```
df = df.set_index('id')
```

Now how do I select the rows where the index column contains "jo"?

Comment: Or we can reset index, do your calculations, then again set 'id' as index, like this: `df.reset_index()[df.reset_index()['id'].str.contains('joe')].set_index('id')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `id` to `index`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['john','joe','zack'],
                        'col':[1,2,3]})

df = df.set_index('id')
df1 = df[df.index.str.contains('jo')]
print (df1)
      col
id       
john    1
joe     2
```